# Are Apple Music radio stations influenced by your likes?

Tags: apple-music

I understand that the more you like certain music tracks, *recommendations* will be provided.

I'm wondering about the Radio specifically. Are the radio stations also influenced by your likes? Similarly to how Pandora works?

[image]

Comment: There are different radios: Stations, based on an artist or song, Beats One, or custom radios found under `New`. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: The radios found under "Radio"